# Is there a way to order rows in a data frame in 2 ways

Tags: r, dataframe

For the following table I need to order the rows so that they are in ascending order of the sum of Column 1 + Column 2, but if column 2 contains a non-zero value, and column 1 contains value 0, these rows should be above those where column 2 contains 0 and column 1 contains a non-zero value.

| Column 1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 20 |
| 0 | 20 |
| 0 | 20 |
| 20 | 20 |

So we get the resulting table:

| Column 1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 |
| 0 | 20 |
| 0 | 20 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 20 | 20 |
| 20 | 20 |

Comment: If you want to order based on sum of two columns you should give a more complicated example. For this example using `dplyr` this works - `df %>% arrange(col1, col2)` Or in base R - `df[do.call(order, df), ]`

Comment: Create dummy variables: one to indicate which rows "must come first" and one to contain the sum of column1 and column2.   Sort on the dummies.  Optionally, drop the dummies when you are done.

Comment: @Limey how do I do this?

Comment: @RonakShah when I did this it put rows 4,5,6 above 1,2,3

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I get the same output as shown in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to first order the entire dataframe and then assemble each part in order to get the desired structure.

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c(0,20,5,20,20,0,0,20), col2=c(20,0,0,0,30,20,10,20))

df <- df[order(df$col1 + df$col2),]
rbind(df[df$col1 == 0,], df[df$col2 == 0,], df[df$col1 != 0 & df$col2 != 0,])
```